# "bin" in package.json will not rename my global binar

Tags: node.js

I have a node project, and in my `package.json` I have this :

```
{
  "name": "pkg-has",
  ...

  "bin": "bin/pkghas",

  ...
}
```

and my binary on my FS is well located (`bin/pkghas`)
but If I install my module globally using `npm install -g .` the binary gets renamed into `pkg-has`. What am I doing wrong here ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I resolve the problem, I had to write :

```
{
  "name": "pkg-has",
  ...
  "bin": {
    "pkghas": "bin/pkghas",
  },
  ...
}
```

Because the binary is not renamed from the filename but from the sub-property of the `bin` property in the `package.json`